# Segregate files with folder conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, if-statement, subdirectory

I want to segregate files in a way where a folder with words starting from X and length 3 alphabets and a copy file which contains the word B09 to a location with subdirectory name contains Xyz.

CURRENT SCENARIO

folder name: KLIOKK-XYZ OPLISAS 24-7-12

file name:   13193.B09.oahsgA, 8810.B14.kajshda

=======================================================

REQUIRED SCENARIO

folder name: XYZ

file name: Doesn't matter but a type of B09

in Python Please

Answer (score 0):

@Vinay, you should look into os.scandir() to get the list of all the directories you want.

Steps to achieve your objective:

1. Scan your folder using os.scandir(). It will give you iterator for all the files
2. Loop over this iterator and check for your condition in name of the file.
3. Rename the file using os.rename()

example code:

```
dir_list = os.scandir('.') #this scans current folder.
for item in dir_list:
  if "B09" in item.name:
    os.rename(item.name, new_path+item.name) # replace path to your desired path
```

Here are the details on [os.scandir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) and [os.rename()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename)

Comment: Hi, Ajay Thanks for the Answer.
Here more details about situations I have multiple dir with XYZ name that contains Multiple B09 files. which I want in one XYZ Dir in relevant B09 files.
basically, this is 365 days data day-wise for different XYZ, ABC, AAA dir combinations with multiple files like B09, A13, AA1, and so on...
Required in all 365 days data in XYZ dir and B09 files from all dir named with XYZ in somewhere in dir

Comment: could you please provide a directory tree of such directory with sample filenames?
https://realpython.com/directory-tree-generator-python/ Something like this.